# Sabre service to get flight availability and price excluding BargainFinderMax

Tags: sabre

Is any Sabre service to get flight availability and price (from given start and end airports and dates).

But excluding BargainFinderMax service (this service is not in our contract).

Answer (score 1):

A possible service it is: OTA_AirLowFareSearchLLSRQ